# Grid UTM coodinates in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping, grids-graticules, utm, srtm

I am trying to use GEE to make maps intended for use on trails with compasses. I have already managed to place the contour lines but I couldn't put the grids with UTM coordinates.

Comment: Apologies if this is not very helpful but have you considered using other tools? GEE excels at raster analysis, not sure if it is the best suited for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the coordinates for any projection using ee.Image.pixelCoordinates.  Then with a little math, you can turn that into a grid.  Set the projection scale to select how close together you want them.  These are at 1km.

```
var proj = ee.Projection("EPSG:32612").atScale(1000)
var coords = ee.Image.pixelCoordinates(proj)
Map.addLayer(coords.subtract(coords.round()).zeroCrossing().reduce('sum').selfMask())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot! Now a new doubt:
Do You know how I can put the coordinates in a box?
Like this: https://www.imagemhost.com.br/image/2yfenC

This is my box: https://www.imagemhost.com.br/image/2yfdpw

Hope you can help again.

Script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/42641a7fa898f566663686cbcec33d52